# Best way to redirect wrong url's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Imagine the scenario, I have:

```
wellspell.com
```

as well

```
wellspeel.com
weelspell.com
weelspeel.com
```

and I want my MVC application to only work with the correct domain name.

My current problem resides on the lack of support on **CNAME** under the current DNS control panel as I can easily add `*.wellspeel.com` and `www.wellspeel.com` but never `wellspeel.com` (only as an ANAME).

What is the easiest configuration so I can redirect `http://wellspeel.com` to `http://wellspell.com` ?

**What I have now** is in my first controller, a simple check using `requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host` and then filtered and redirect the user with

```
requestContext.HttpContext.Response.RedirectPermanent("http://wellspell.com");
```

But this is already inside the Controller Initialization... can I do the redirect before reaching the controller?

I was looking to the documentation regarding [`UrlRoutingModule`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutingmodule%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) but after a few attempts I was lost...

Can anyone point me the right direction, or does anyone has the issue and how did you guys solved it?

---

*P.S.* I was also thinking I could create a simple Handler in a new website and in that website bindings add all "bad" domains and redirect from there, using maybe a simple XML configuration to be easier to update...

Answer (score 1):

If you are running IIS 7 or later you could just make sure of the [HTTP Redirect](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect) and skip having to stand up any code.

**Edit**: For some reason I was assuming you were standing up IIS sites for each possible domain.  If you are just setting up one IIS site and including multiple bindings for each possible domain, then you might want to look into using the [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) rules (this would still let you skip having to configure any code as the rules will be executed before the MVC pipeline).

Specifically, I think you would be interested in the `HTTP_HOST` condition input.

Here is an (untested) example:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SpellingErrorOne" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^weelspeel.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://wellspell.com" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

You would just need to add a rule for each domain you want to handle.  The `<condition>` acts as criteria that has to validate in order for the action (e.g. redirect) to be executed.